# Timer not stopping on segue

Tags: swift, asynchronous, timer

I'm instantiating a timer like this:

```
func runTimer() {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if self.timer.isValid == false {
      self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.025, target: self, selector: (#selector(ResultVCViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
      RunLoop.current.add(self.timer, forMode: .commonModes)          
      }
    }
  }
```

and deallocating it like this:

```
func stopTimer() {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if self.timer.isValid {
      self.timer.invalidate()
      self.isTimerRunning = false
      print("stopped timer")
    } else {
      print("timer isn't running!")
    }
  }
}
```

When called like this, `stopTimer()` isn't being called (no console output , timer still running, if I add a breakpoint, it's ignored but the segue is performed):

```
@IBAction func aboutLicensebtn(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
  //debug
  stopTimer()
  performSegue(withIdentifier: "AboutLicense", sender: nil)
}
```

And this works as expected:

```
@IBAction func goBack(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
  stopTimer()
  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

How can I stop the timer when performing a segue?

Edit: The timer stops when put into `viewDidDisappear` but I don't want this behavior.

Edit: I tried performing the segue on main as well, but the result is unchanged.

**Clarification on why I'm starting and stopping the timer the way I am:**

It's added to a `RunLoop` to use for `.commonModes` so the timer doesn't stop when the view is scrolled.

It's started and stopped on main to ensure its being started and stopped on the same thread.

Comment: When you put a breakpoint in `aboutLicensebtn` and stepped through the code, what did you see?

Comment: The breakpoint is also ignored - and yes, the segue is performed

Comment: And what does that tell you?

Comment: I wouldn't be asking if I knew...

Comment: The segue _is_ performed? Where did you put the breakpoint?

Comment: initially at the end of the block, then moved it to the stopTimer() line, either way the code continues to execute

Answer (score 3):

Do **not** add a *scheduled* timer to a runloop.

The most reliable way to start and stop a timer is to use an optional property and check this (the dispatch to the main queue is not needed at all):

```
var timer : Timer?
```

---

```
func runTimer() {
    if timer == nil {
       timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.025, 
                     target: self, 
                     selector: #selector(updateTimer), 
                     userInfo: nil, 
                     repeats: true)
    }
}
```

---

```
func stopTimer() {
    if timer != nil {
      timer!.invalidate()
      timer = nil
      print("stopped timer")
    } else {
      print("timer isn't running!")
    }
}
```

Comment: I added it to a runloop as part of debugging it. I wanted to make sure the timer was being instantiated and deallocated on the same thread as this has fixed similar issues in the past with no hit to performance.

Comment: To clarify, I added it to a runloop to use it for  .commonModes as I was having an issue with the timer stopping on scrolling a scrollview. Adding and deallocating on main was to solve this issue with the timer not stopping on segue.  Also, I tried your solution, but there's no change.